# comma in csv file is recognized as separator even though it's inside double quote

Tags: mysql, csv

I am struggling for 2 days...Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

**What I did:**

I've exported some data as csv file (mysql). It's separated by comma, enclosed by double quotes.

the query looks like..

```
select * from table1 
INTO OUTFILE 'sample.csv'
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

and this is what sample.csv looks like:

```
"post_name","post_title","post_date","post_thumbnail","post_mainimage","post_content,"meta_description","text2","editor_id"
    "post1","title!｜this is title","1451905200","123.jpg","123.jpg","<p>this is description</p> <h2> this is description <br>\"this is description \"</h2><p><span style=\"line-height: 1.8;\">「this is description」</span></p><p><img alt=\"aa,bb,cc \" class=\"fr-fin fr-dib\" src=\"/files/123.jpg\" title=\"aa,bb,cc \" width=\"300\"></p><p>this is description</p><p><strong>this is description</strong></p><p><span style=\"font-size: 13px;\">this is description<br>this is description</span><br></p>","this is meta_description","this is text2","12"
```

**Problem:**

when I open this file on Mac Numbers (and other csv viewers as well), it seems like comma after 'aa' is recognized as separator, and therefore 'bb' is placed in the next cell in the table, which is unexpected result because I thought that comma inside double quote wouldn't be treated as separator.

Any advice and help will be greatly appreciated!

**edit:**

I accidentally deleted double quote while I editing.
so `"post_content` was actually `"post_content"`

thanks for the comments!! I will read through when I get home!

Comment: *when I open this file on Mac Numbers (and other csv viewers as well)* This is viewer issue? MySQL can do nothing with third-party software... As a recommendation - use some char which is absent in values with guarantee, and set your viewer to use this custom columns delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is a double quote missing in the header:

```
,"post_content,
```

Second, it looks like the parser doesn't see the `\` as an escape for the embedded double quotes.

Using `\"` is 'Linux style', where `""` is 'Windows style'. Your data also uses `\r\n` which is Windows style - so maybe the parser is confused?

Anyway, you should tell the parser to use `\` as escape character, or just use `"` as the escape character when exporting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
Double quote is my mistake, I edited the original post.

Changing `escaped by “\\”` to  `escaped by ‘“‘`,   fixed the issue!

Comment: Another issue I got after fixing this issue: 
Before I changed escape character to double quote, field with null value was exported as `"\n"`. After change, it became `“N` (Note that there’s no closing double quote) This made multiple values be inside the same cell. For example `“N, some other value”`, in one cell. Not sure why the double quote is missing.. Do you have idea?
I fixed this issue by putting `IFNULL(column, “”)` for all the nullable columns, which is not pretty but it woks.. not sure if there’s better ways..

Comment: It looks like Mysql is escaping the `N`. What if you omit the `ESCAPED BY` option? -- Also make sure you are using the right quotes (i.e. ASCII 34 `"`). (I don't have Mysql installed, so can't test)

Comment: If I remove ESCAPED BY option, I get the same issue as before (comma treated as separator).

Answer (score 0):

```
"post_name","post_title","post_date","post_thumbnail","post_mainimage","post_content","meta_description","text2","editor_id"
"post1","title!｜this is title","1451905200","123.jpg","123.jpg","<p>this is description</p> <h2> this is description <br>\"this is description \"</h2><p><span style=\"line-height: 1.8;\">「this is description」</span></p><p><img alt=\"aa,bb,cc \" class=\"fr-fin fr-dib\" src=\"/files/123.jpg\" title=\"aa,bb,cc \" width=\"300\"></p><p>this is description</p><p><strong>this is description</strong></p><p><span style=\"font-size: 13px;\">this is description<br>this is description</span><br></p>","this is meta_description","this is text2","12"
```

I think there was a misplaced double quote after "post content".

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, 
I accidentally deleted double quote while editing the post. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You want this to export to an Excel-readable .csv

```
select * from table1 
  INTO OUTFILE 'sample.csv'
  CHARACTER SET utf8
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Changing `escaped by “\\”` to `escaped by ‘“‘`, fixed the issue!

Comment: Another issue I got after fixing this issue: 
Before I changed escape character to double quote, field with null value was exported as `"\n"`. After change, it became `“N` (Note that there’s no closing double quote) This made multiple values be inside the same cell. For example `“N, some other value”`, in one cell. Not sure why the double quote is missing.. Do you have idea?
I fixed this issue by putting `IFNULL(column, “”)` for all the nullable columns, which is not pretty but it woks.. not sure if there’s better ways..

Comment: Weird on the null columns. I'll investigate. By the way it looks to me like you're using fancy quotation marks like `“` `”` `‘` in some of your text rather than the ASCII ones `"` `'`. Careful! sometimes text editors mess things up in an effort to be literary.

Comment: Right, thanks for reminding!  I checked my queries and they were all ASCII quotation marks. (and If I don’t I get error anyways)

Comment: Tested both `optionally enclosed by` and `enclosed by` just to test this affects the result, but no changes><